# HostingEnvironment.MapPath returning null in ASP.Net MVC NUnit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nunit

I have to test a Service using NUnit with this code:

```
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(); 
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename =   HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Modules/Proy.Notification/Web.config");
_configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

The problem is that HostingEnvironment.MapPath is returning null. Is there any way to mock my config or make it point to the right folder?

BTW: I can't change the code I'm testing.